# $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{1}{a^2+6bc}\geq\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{1}{a^2+2} $ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^+},\ a^2+b^2+c^2=1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I have been trying to prove the following inequality:

$\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{1}{a^2+6bc}\geq\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{1}{a^2+2} $ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^+},\ a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

I have tried applying Jensen (from which I just found a useless lower bound for the sum on the RHS), I have then tried using the condition given to homegenize the inequality but that led to an algebraic mess from which I couldn't find any useful information and lastly I tried with Lagrange multipliers but I have had no luck with that technique either.

So, I would appreciate an hint about how to go about proving this inequality, thanks.

(Source: exercise from E. Chen handout on inequalities)